# Is there any point where commercial calling could be illegal?

Tags: phonecall, telemarketing

I've been recently looking around for a vehicle insurance and I filled up a form to get some offers and compare prices between some companies, but now one of them keeps callin me every hour.

I could just block the number and that would be the end of it, but I'm curious to see how many times they are going to call me without response until they tire out.

Now this question comes up to my mind, is it legal to do this kind of "marketing strategy" this many times? I mean, I'm not a lawer but isn't there any point that is considered a hounding offense?

Comment: The point comes at the time you pick up the phone and tell them not to call you anymore.

Comment: They don't tire out. They don't quit.  They don't know pain, or fear.  You can't run or hide, they will just keep calling and calling until you make them stop.  They are robots, and that's what they are programmed to do ...

Comment: What country are you in? If in the USA, insurance companies are regulated state-by-state. You could complain to the agency in your state that regulates insurance companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, the [National Do Not Call Registry](https://consumer.ftc.gov/articles/national-do-not-call-registry-faqs#what_doesn%27t_do) clearly does not prevent a company that you already have a connection with from calling you. From the linked FAQ:

> Companies can call you if you’ve recently done business with them, or if you’ve given them written permission to call

I don't know all the details, but I suspect that completing a web form is treated as "given them written permission to call". That means the initial calls are legitimate, which makes sense since you asked the company for information, even if you didn't *expect* it to result in sales calls.

However, the FAQ also says:

> But if you ask them not to call you, they have to stop. Be sure to write down the date you asked them to stop.

If they are a *legitimate* company, then if you tell them clearly "do not call this number any more" they will stop. Unfortunately, many companies are not legitimate, law-abiding companies and will keep calling anyway.

My recommendation:

- If you have not already done so, sign up for the Do Not Call Registry. It won't stop everything, and in particular won't stop overseas VOIP-based scammers, but it will cut down on some calls, and it provides a legal basis for stopping calls.
- Each and every time they call, inform them that you want them to stop calling your number, that you are on the Do Not Call Registry, and that you will report them to the Federal Trade Commission.